# How to stretch this quadratic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics, graphing-functions, transformation

I have a function
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{3p}{5d^2}\right)x^2+\frac{2p}{5d}x$$

where $p$ and $d$ are constants. ($x_2$, on the diagram is $d$)

Given two points $(x_1,s)$ and $(x_2,p)$ on the function, as labelled on the diagram:

[image]

Currently, $dx=x_2-x_1$, I would like to be able to stretch all the function such that the part of the function in $dx $ become stretched to a length of $ x_2$, while keeping it between $y=p$ and $y=s$ knowing that $s$ is a constant I choose between $0$ and $p$.
So in simple, I want to keep the same function for its $y$ values but spread these values so that the $y$s of the $dx$ part are spread over a distance of $x_2 (d)$. Like if we zoomed on the graph or changed the scale of $x$. The more $s$ is big, the more the graph is zoomed.
Thank you.

[SOLVED] with the help of the answer here : https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualMath/comments/iid9o7/how_to_stretch_this_quadratic_function/g376as2?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
this is the function needed : $$f(x)=\left(\frac{3p}{5d^2}\right)(x\cdot\left(1-\frac{x_1}{d}\right))^2+\frac{2p}{5d}(x\cdot\left(1-\frac{x_1}{d}\right))$$
where $x_1 = $[image]

Comment: Could you instead label points on your graph (i.e. put $S$ and $D$ as points)?

Comment: Ok, I edited the picture :)

Comment: Does [this image](https://i.imgur.com/pTjRz5z.png) show what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, I want the dx in your picture take "d" space instead of d - s

Comment: So you want $dx=x_2$?

Comment: Yes exactly, this is what I need

Comment: Alright, let me edit your post.

Comment: Does that edit work?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much !

Comment: Perhaps you want "dx" to be $x_2-x_1$?

Comment: One quick way to do it is just to change the scale along the $x-$axis.

Comment: I want dx to be at a length equal to that between zero and x2 (d). So it's equivalent to changing the scale of x but how can I have a function that does this ?

Comment: You said that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are given, so also $dx$ must be considered "given". Changing the function (which is defined by other "given values") does not change these given values and changing these values does not change the function. You will have to specify what parameters are to be changed while keeping or targetting a certain property (of the function).

Comment: x1 is the point where the function touch y=s and x2 = d. I need to get a function that stretch more and more the s grow.

Comment: You can change the scale of the $x$ axis (in effect) by a factor of $k$ by replacing every $x$ in your function's formula with $x/k.$ This will cause the new function to pass through the points $(kx_1,s)$ and $(kx_2,p).$ If you make $k$ large enough then you will find that $kx_2 - kx_1 = x_2.$ Is that the kind of thing you are looking for? If not, perhaps you can draw a picture to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] with the help of the answer here : https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualMath/comments/iid9o7/how_to_stretch_this_quadratic_function/g376as2?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
this is the function needed : $$f(x)=\left(\frac{3p}{5d^2}\right)(x\cdot\left(1-\frac{x_1}{d}\right))^2+\frac{2p}{5d}(x\cdot\left(1-\frac{x_1}{d}\right))$$
where $x_1 = $[image]